# unexpected '}' when running source()

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have read multiple forums on error with regards to unexpected '}' error. However, its seems that most people tend to forget a bracket or mix them up. I'm unable to see what is wrong with my code here.

Here is the code:

```
typemean <- function(directory, type, id = 1:332) {
    files_list <- list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE) ##creates a list of files
    dat<-data.frame()                                   ##creates an empty data frame
    for (i in seq_along(id)) {                          ##loops through the files in id subset, rbingind them tgt
        dat<-rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[id[i]])) 
    }
    mean(dat[,type],na.rm=TRUE)                         ##identifies the mean of the type while removing NAs
}
```

i get the correct answers when running the code itself. However, when saving it as a .R format, i get an error while using the source() function.

```
> save(typemean,file="typemean.R")
> source("typemean.R")
Error in source("typemean.R") : typemean.R:12:2: unexpected '}'
11:  mean(dat[,type],na.rm=TRUE)##identifies the mean of the type while removing NAs
12:  }
     ^
>
```

Comment: Typically you use `load` on a `save`d object.  It works fine

Answer (score 1):

`save()` saves an R representation of the funciton object, not source code,  You want to use `load()` to load the stored object, not `source()`, like this:

```
# save the function to file
save(typemean,file="typemean.R")
# remove it from the current environment
rm(typemean)
# load the stored function from file
load("typemean.R")
# see that we have loaded the same function
typemean
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my assignment requires that I start the code with source () instead load(). How can I approach that in this case? Thanks!

Comment: there are several optoins.  The simplest is to choose 'new script' from the file menu and write the script there. ( you can also use your favorite text editor for this).   The other option is to call `dput(typemean,file="typemean.R")`